# Georeferencer stopped working

Tags: qgis-3, georeferencing

I georeferenced some things about a month ago no problem. However now when I click my reference plugin it does not open the Georeferencer dialogue box or the georeference drop down menu. It is enabled it just does not start.

Has this happened to anyone?

Comment: have you checked the in the plugin manager to see if you need to update the plugin?